# PHP mass mail script shows extra file in outlook

Tags: php, email, outlook

I use PHP script to send email with multiple attachments, it works great for gmail, but in Microsoft Outlook i also see blank file `ATT00010.txt` (random numbers.) as attachment. And when i send email from outlook with multiple attachments as well it does not show no file like this.

I echo'ed output from email script and there is no such file in code. Can someone tell me how to remove this file from outlook?

Email script is below.

```
// array with filenames to be sent as attachment
$files = array("file_1.ext","file_2.ext","file_3.ext",......);

// email fields: to, from, subject, and so on
$to = "mail@mail.com";
$from = "mail@mail.com"; 
$subject ="My subject"; 
$message = "My message";
$headers = "From: $from";

// boundary 
$semi_rand = md5(time()); 
$mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x"; 

// headers for attachment 
$headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" . "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" . " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\""; 

// multipart boundary 
$message = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" . "--{$mime_boundary}\n" . "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n" . "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" . $message . "\n\n"; 
$message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";

// preparing attachments
for($x=0;$x<count($files);$x++){
    $file = fopen($files[$x],"rb");
    $data = fread($file,filesize($files[$x]));
    fclose($file);
    $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));
    $message .= "Content-Type: {\"application/octet-stream\"};\n" . " name=\"$files[$x]\"\n" . 
    "Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" . " filename=\"$files[$x]\"\n" . 
    "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" . $data . "\n\n";
    $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";
}

// send

$ok = @mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers); 
if ($ok) { 
    echo "<p>mail sent to $to!</p>"; 
} else { 
    echo "<p>mail could not be sent!</p>"; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The *last* boundary line in a `multipart/*` message must have `--` appended *at the end*, in addition to what all of the other boundary lines have. A consumer can use that to recognize the end of a message.

Apparently Outlook treats the absence of the correct ending as an indication that the message has been truncated, and then does the best it can to display whatever it did receive.

Comment: Could you explain what i need to do in order to achieve it, its my first time sending multiple email i added $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n--"; to the code but it still creates this file.

Comment: end looks like this 
AAAhANTA4nNKAgAAXAUAABAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA4cUAAGRvY1Byb3BzL2FwcC54bWxQSwUGAAAA ABUAFQA4BQAAYckAAAAA --==Multipart_Boundary_xb62e473cba4f51ba9e457cab77e64605x --



From: admin@site.com MIME-Version: 1.0 Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="==Multipart_Boundary_xb62e473cba4f51ba9e457cab77e64605x"

Comment: The `--` needs to go _before_ the `\n` that ends the last line, not on a line of its own after it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want something that's a little less of a pain to use and send attachments with, try Swift Mailer. (swiftmailer.org)  I've been using it in my projects and it works great.

Here's an example:

```
$message = Swift_Message::newInstance()
  ->setSubject('Webinar Registration')
  ->setFrom(array('replyto@example.org' => 'From Name'))
  ->setTo(array('destination@example.org'))
  ->setBody($MESSAGE_TEXT)
  ;

$message->attach(Swift_Attachment::fromPath('SOME_FILE_PATH'));
$transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('127.0.0.1', 25);
$mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);
$result = $mailer->send($message);
```

Just my two cents.

Otherwise, I was going to mention what someone else already beat me to -- check the boundaries.

Answer (score -1):

Its my second account, i actually found solution and don't need no library or class at all although i might turn this into class and add some stuff, its always better to have full understanding of process not just from, to, files etc fields.

Solution is simple here just replace last part with

```
    if ($x == count($files)-1) 
        $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}--\r\n";
    else
        $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";
```

\r is not necessary

if you just put -- it will use it many times inside loop IF checks if this is last loop.

Comment: "Its always better to have full understanding of process not just from, to, files etc fields." I hope you never use jQuery or any other libraries for Javascript or PHP, then. If you want to get an understanding, just look at the library's source. Or examples online. But there's no need to reinvent the wheel and make it more difficult for future people to maintain. (I also remember people suggesting not using the `mail()` function because of a poor implementation, but I don't have a source to prove it.)